# Run timer in a specific time (swift)

Tags: swift, timer, swift3, nstimer

I have an app that takes the time and time interval from a user and starts to count down at that time.
when I try to start the timer at the time that I have, it freaks out and not working.

this is the func that runs the timer:

```
 func runTimer(){

    let timer = Timer(fireAt: firstMealTime, interval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
}
```

and this is the `updateTimer` func:

```
  if seconds < 1 {
        timerRepeat! -= 1
        updateMealLeftLabel(numberOfMeal: timerRepeat)
        resetTimer()
    }else{
        seconds -= 1
        updateTimerLabel()
    }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to start the timer at a specific time

Comment: Oh as in scheduling when the timer goes off?

Comment: no, I need the timer to start at the time that the user pick

Answer (score 1):

You can check your timer definition like this:

```
var seconds = YourCountdownValue // (in seconds) for example 100 seconds.

func runTimer(){
   firstMealTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(10.0) // This line is for testing. Countdown will be start in 10 seconds.
   let timer = Timer(fireAt: firstMealTime, interval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
}

func updateTimer() {
    if seconds < 1 {
       timerRepeat! -= 1
       updateMealLeftLabel(numberOfMeal: timerRepeat)
       print("finished") //for testing
       resetTimer()
    }else{
       seconds -= 1
       print(seconds) //for testing
       updateTimerLabel()
   }
}
```

Comment: firstMealTime is a Date variable that hold the time 

 firstMealTime = defaults.object(forKey: "FirstMealTime") as? Date ?? Date()

Comment: it still acts the same.

Comment: I tested it with _firstMealTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(10.0)_ and it's working without error. It starts counting down after 10 seconds from current datetime. What is your firstMealTime value, can you debug it?

Comment: firstMealTime is a Date value. the user picks the time from a DatePicker and after he confirms the time in the datePicker there is a sague to another view controller that show a timer. I need the time to count down from the time the user define

Comment: I understand it but i mean it's value while in debug. For example this is a working sample value:  _2017-04-17 09:00:46 +0000_. What is your firstMealTime's value?

Comment: Right now the value is  2017-04-17 10:35:44 +0000

Comment: I added some test lines to my answer and updated it. You can track seconds. Maybe you can review your _updateMealLeftLabel_, _updateTimerLabel_ and _resetTimer()_ functions. Because timer is now working for me.